Why is the stack segment not explicit in ELF files?
Everything mapped in memory is explicit in ELF files except the stack segment. The stack segment is mapped automatically.
Why is the stack segment not like other segments, with explicit settings in ELF files?
Some programs might want a specific stack size that does not necessarily match the limit set by ulimit -s. So they can't use the automatically allocated stack. The program should know better than the user how much stack memory it actually needs.
Some programs might not need a stack at all. For example garbage collected languages may want to allocate their stack frames on the heap.
Wouldn't it be simpler and better for the stack segment to be explicit?
The stack could either be a segment in the ELF file (perhaps with an "automatically growable" bit set), or it could be mmaped by the process itself at startup.

Does the Stack Overflow answer Why is there no stack segment in an object (ELF) files? help?

@ChesterGillon Thanks but I don't think that answer makes sense. It doesn't really answer the question why this particular mapping is done automatically. Also it's not true that all segments in an executable ELF file correspond to memory mapped from the file. ELF files already support zero-initialized memory segments that aren't mapped from the file.

The difference between the stack and other segments is that compilation units never need to store anything in the stack. Other segments might not need to be represented physically in a compilation unit or the final executable (BSS is a typical example), but they contain objects which might need to be represented by symbols.
Consider this:
int foo;

Compiled, this results in an object file with a four-byte BSS segment and a foo symbol pointing to that segment. This must be represented in the object file, there’s no way around it; but that’s not the case for the stack (or the heap), so it isn’t represented in the binary.
Programs with specific stack requirements can call setrlimit themselves to ensure that they have enough room (within the hard limit). On Linux, programs need to have a stack set up for them before they start executing because the stack is part of the psABI and is used to pass information to the program (the program’s arguments, environment, and auxiliary vector) — see for example section 3.4 of the x86-64 System V psABI. The stack is also part of the calling convention, so a program may not even be able to call functions required to allocate a stack if it doesn’t already have a stack (for example on 32-bit x86).

It makes sense. Then the real question: why preallocate a stack at all? Why don't processes just use mmap to allocate their stack (or stacks) of any location and size they want. This would give them full control over this rather than relying on the user to set the right stack limit.

See the updated answer.

Makes sense that the stack needs to be there because of the args and environment! I forgot about that. Thanks.
Regarding setting setrlimit I've noticed that it doesn't always work, because if the initial limit is smaller, the kernel doesn't necessarily leave enough space for the larger stack (even if the request is below the hard limit). So to be sure you still have to allocate a second stack elsewhere.
I think that perhaps it would make sense to have a tiny initial stack allocated, and have each program move its stack elsewhere.
